# Using a Combination of INNER and FULL OUTER Joins to Get Desired Data Set

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, inner-join, outer-join

I’ve got 5 Tables:

- Patients Table 'PAT'
- Patient Orders 'ORD'
- Patient Comments 'Comm'
- Patient Antigens 'Ant'
- Patient MRNs 'MRN'

Information in the following four tables:

- Pat has all of our patients information
- Ord only has orders from the last four years, joined to the Pat table on Patient ID
- Comm has all patient comments, joined on the Pat table on Patient ID
- Ant has all antigens entered on patients, joined on the Pat table on Patient ID
- MRN has all medical record numbers of patients, joined on the Pat table on Patient ID

What I’m trying to do it make sure I have all patients that appear in the Ord, Comm, Ant, and MRN tables and the join it to the Pat table to get information like first name, last name, sex, DOB...

So I’m trying to figure out how best to join these tables together to make sure I don’t include patients that don’t appear in the Ord, Comm, Ant, or MRN tables.

If I join the tables to my main patient table with left outer joins, I'll get all patients regardless if they have an order, comment, antigen, or MRN.

```
Select * from Pat
Left Outer Join Ord on Pat.X=Ord.X
Left Outer Join Comm on Pat.X=Comm.X
Left Outer Join Ant on Pat.X=Ant.X
Left Outer Join MRN on Pat.X=MRN.X
```

I've attempted to make a visual diagram of what I'm looking for:
[image: Expected Results]

My ideal query would return all Patients except for 4 and 10 because they do not have any orders, antigens, comments, or a MRN.

I was thinking I could perform FULL OUTER JOINS on the ORD, ANT, COMM, and MRN tables and then take those results and and join it to the PAT table.

```
Select *
FROM P50DATA.AGABFL1 ANT
FULL OUTER JOIN P50DATA.ORDMSTL1 ORD ON ANT.AGACCT=ORD.OPACCT
FULL OUTER JOIN P50DATA.DCMTRNL5 COMM ON ANT.AGACCT=COMM.DCACCT
FULL OUTER JOIN P50DATA.HOSPIDL1 HOS ON ANT.AGACCT=HOS.APACCT
```

But I don't know how to then take this data set and marry it to the Pat table so I could then get my patient information.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is your goal to get one row per patient with an indicator for each category, as in your diagram?  Or do you not care about the indicators and really want just the patient IDs?

Comment: My goal is to have all Patients listed who have at least one record in any of those 4 tables. But no Patients listed who do not have a record in one of the four tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't have to be too complicated.

`ORD`, `ANT`, `COMM`, and `MRN` don't have to join to each other, because you don't need the records in any one of them to match any other one.  You just need to know whether they have records for a given patient or not.

There are many ways to construct such a query; here's one:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     PAT
WHERE    EXISTS (
     SELECT  1
     FROM    ORD
     WHERE   ORD.X = PAT.X
     )
   OR    EXISTS (
     SELECT  1
     FROM    ANT
     WHERE   ANT.X = PAT.X
     )
   OR    EXISTS (
     SELECT  1
     FROM    COMM
     WHERE   COMM.X = PAT.X
     )
   OR    EXISTS (
     SELECT  1
     FROM    MRN
     WHERE   MRN.X = PAT.X
    )
```

Because you are querying the `Patient` table without joining it to anything, you don't have to worry about duplicate records, and because you're just checking existence for `ORD`, `ANT`, `COMM`, and `MRN`, you don't have to worry about exactly how many records each of them has for a given patient.

Comment: Interesting. I've never written a query like this before.  It works but I'm going to have to dig in so I understand it better.  Thanks!